# Reformating a portion of my netbook to reallocate space to Ubuntu (already installed)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning

I have dual boot system.

I would like to reformat the Windows portion of my Hard Drive and reallocate that space to the Ubuntu 14.04 lts that I have already installed.

Is this possible?

Comment: I have reconsidered this and feel like the best bet would be to just reformat the whole net book and start over with just ubuntu 14.04.  Sounds like it would just be easier.  I need to be able to do this with a flash drive so: will I wipe out the software that I need to do this?  Is there a link/video I can go to to have step by step instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Boot windows and use the windows tools to shrink one of the Windows partitions (one with free space, obviously).  Then boot into a live Ubuntu CD and use gparted to increase the size of your Ubuntu partition to fill up the free space.

Comment: It is not that simple.  Assuming the Windows partition is before the Ubuntu partition, the partition has to be shrunk from outside Windows, the Ubuntu partition moved and expanded, and then GRUB reinstalled.

Comment: I have done it this way many times.  But yes, depending on the layout of the partitions, it can be more complicated.